# How do I display varchar as percentage, while aliasing, and linking multiple tables using the same variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four CSV tables of census data. I’m trying to develop a query that will allow me to search one variable which exists in all four tables (a FIPS code). Also, display selected data from only certain columns of each table, while aliasing the headers, and modifying some of the results as a percentage, and/or money.

Table details:

1. The respective table names are DP02, DP03, DP04, and DP05.
2. All four tables can be linked by the GEO_id2 variable.
3. Each table has close to one hundred rows, or more.
4. Aside from the GEO_id headers, the remaining headers have names like HC03_VC01, 02, etc.
5. All of the data is in VARCHAR format. The data consists of numbers representing different types of variables: 63.4 in table stands for 63.4%, 47721 stands for $47,721, etc.

My Goal:

To be able to punch in a particular GEO_id2 and search all four tables, returning only selected rows of data from those tables, and displaying them in a user-friendly format (e.g., instead of HC01 listed in the header, it should say “Median_family_income”). Additionally, the results should be listed in their appropriate format (e.g., 63.4 should display 63.4%, 47721 should display $47,721, etc.).

I have managed to do much of this using the following query:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT
ACS_DP03.GEO_id2 AS FIPS,
ACS_DP03.HC01_VC114 AS Median_family_income, 
ACS_DP02.HC03_VC11 AS Female_householder, 
ACS_DP05.HC03_VC101 AS AmerIndian_Alaskan,
ACS_DP04.HC03_VC65 AS Owner_Occupied
  FROM [Census].[dbo].[ACS_DP03]
  INNER JOIN ACS_DP02 ON ACS_DP03.GEO_id2 = ACS_DP02.GEO_id2
  INNER JOIN ACS_DP05 ON ACS_DP03.GEO_id2 = ACS_DP05.GEO_id2
  INNER JOIN ACS_DP04 ON ACS_DP03.GEO_id2 = ACS_DP04.GEO_id2
  WHERE ACS_DP03.GEO_id2 = 18097360405
  AND ACS_DP02.GEO_id2 = 18097360405
  AND ACS_DP05.GEO_id2 = 18097360405
  AND ACS_DP04.GEO_id2 = 18097360405;
```

I can get the data to link up and display the right variables, but the formatting not exact. Also, as you can see from my SQL query, I would have to punch in the GEO_id2 multiple times.

Questions:

1. Is there a way I can shorten the WHERE & AND clauses to only punch in my GEO_id2 once?
2. How can I change the variables to their respective formats? (e.g., 47721 to $47,721, 22 to 22%, etc.) I thought I could combine ALIAS and CAST statements somehow, but I have not been successful in finding examples or trying it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Question 1., only one where condition is enough for `GEO_id2` because your tables are already joined with `GEO_id2`

For Question 2. you can use `FORMAT`. Ex:

`FORMAT(ACS_DP03.HC01_VC114,'$#####')`  or

`FORMAT(ACS_DP03.HC01_VC114, 'C', 'en-us')` --> `C` stands for Currency

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-format-with-numeric-types)

Comment: Hi Simonare. For question 2 I tried both options. I get the following message: "Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function."

Comment: If your datatype is already varchar then you cannot use FORMAT, INSTEAD format it manually or first CONVERT varchar to number then format it

Comment: Thank you again. Two follow-up questions: Is there a way to check multiple GEO_id2s? Something like a WHERE IN statement with multiple OR conditions, but with an AND instead? I would like to be able to check, and display, several GEO_id2s at once, if possible. Last, I’m guessing what you mean by _format it manually_ is to upload the data in the appropriate format. But regarding the _CONVERT varchar to number then format it_ could you (or anyone else), give me some insight on how to frame that part of the statement? Thank you again. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I really couldn't understand what you mean. You may consider to open new thread may be? to better visualise your intend? and If you believe that this answer helped you please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer

Comment: No problem Simonare. Thank you again for your help!